# Is it a good practice to use non-static variables or invoke a non-static method (access using the object instance) within the static method?

Tags: java

**With example**: Is it a good practice to use non-static variables or invoke a non-static method (access using the object instance) within the *static* method?

public class StringTest {

```
public String string = "helloworld";

public String subString(String str)
{
    str = str.substring(1, 4);
    return str;
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stubs
    StringTest st = new StringTest();
    System.out.println("substring "+st.subString(st.string));
}
```

}                                                                                        I am invoking the *subString* method using the instance of the class.Also passing the argument *string* using the instance. Is this a good practice? or should the static methods only modify static variables and invoke static methods.

Comment: I don't think you can even do that. Care providing an example?

Comment: (In the thread: people providing non-answers to a wrong question)

Comment: It's not only not 'good practice', it's impossible. Not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler will complain if you try to do it. Variables declared inside an static method are static implicitly. If you try to access a non-static one, your program won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

Try it and you will see that this is impossible. You can access only static members from a static method.

Answer (score 2):

A quick illustration that hopefully gives you a one-view summary:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are passing your instance to the static method (or have a static field pointing to it) when calling its methods, if that is the case then yes it is ok, and it's not against anything I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice. You should never do that. And ,actually ,in java you could never achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can access non-static members from static context by making instance , but This is not  a good practice to call static members from non-static context ...
http://javaguideforall.blogspot.in/2013/04/why-non-static-variable-cannot-be.html